# How to get min/max values on form that returns multiple records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a form that returns multiple records from a table. Each of these records has a field indicating what the measurement was and the measurement's value. My form's record source pulls the appropriate ID's set of measurements and values, and then I want to write each of these measurements to different text boxes on the form.

The problem is that I'm also keeping track of the date this data was updated, and want to include only the data pulled based on the "date updated" selected at the top of the form.

When I go to pull the measurement value into a text box (with something like `max(iif(Measurement="Acidity", [Value],[Null]))` I get `#Error` all down my form. This had been working earlier today, and as I've been developing the form something changed and now it no longer works (everything but the date returned is saying `#Error`). I've set it to Requery when the form loads and whenever the date selected is changed.

EDIT:
This form is actually a subform of another main form. The main form has a control called MemberID which a user can use to select the Member they want information about. This is based on a query that pulls from a table the information related to that MemberID (one row per MemberID). When the form loads, the query behind the main form needs to be requeried to get the data for the selected MemberID.

Then there is this subform causing the problems. On this subform is a "Data Updated" drop down box, which lists the possible dates that the data was updated. When one chooses a particular "Data updated" in the drop down box, this chooses the *latest* data for all the data measures *up to that date selected*. This means the form's record source pulls about 10 records in my case.

Then, on this subform I try to layout these 10 records' values in different text boxes. So, in my acidity case above, I would say `iif(Measurement="Acidity", [Value], Null)`. Because there are 10 rows returned, I will end up with 9 Nulls and 1 value, and to get that value I use the max function, so the text box's control source reads: `max(iif(Measurement="Acidity",[Value],Null)).`

The strange thing is this code was working this morning, until later this afternoon when I was filling in the remaining text boxes with similar code, and then it stopped working. I had also renamed the boxes from Text71 to more relevant names, but none of these are referenced in the code.

Comment: You need to show some code...

Comment: Why are you not using the footer for these ?

Comment: Sorry for the long response time, I was in a meeting for several hours. Here are more details that may help, and some code.

Comment: Done. I only put that note about the meeting in there in case anyone was waiting on me for several hours to respond :)